# Divide two cell values PHP Excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm Trying to divide value in cell 'A2 to A13' by 'B2 to B13' respectively.

```
require_once 'phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$F=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$Line=2;

while($Trs=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
    $F->setCellValue('H2','{=(A'.($Line).' / B'.($Line).')}')
      ->setCellValue('I'.$Line,'{=A2:A13/B2:B13}');
    ++$Line;
}
```

I have tried two ways to get the desired result

1: `setCellValue('H2','{=(A'.($Line).' / B'.($Line).')}')`

2: `setCellValue('I'.$Line,'{=A2:A13/B2:B13}')`

But none of these are working as desired:

Output 1: `{=(A13 / B13)}`

Output 2: `{=A2:A13/B2:B13}`

**By desired Output I mean if value of A2 = 10 and B2 = 5 Then H2 and I2 should result in displaying '2' and not the formula used to get '2' as result.**

[Example xls file](http://unizhost.com/a/htm5dem/report.xls)

**From H2 to H13 is what I actually need.**

Can anyone tell me what's the correct way to get the desired output? Am I missing any library file that needs to be included on the page?

Comment: can you show example of desired output?

Comment: Array formulae aren't supported in PHPExcel; but I don't understand why you're trying to set this as an array formula in the first place

Comment: @MarkS: Edited my question hope I'm clear now.

Comment: @MarkBaker: Since I don't know how to get it the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array formulae aren't supported in PHPExcel; but I don't understand why you're trying to set this as an array formula in the first place (at least for H2)

For H2

```
$F->setCellValue('H2','=A' . $Line . ' / B' . $Line);
```

But you realise that you're simply overwriting this with a different value in each iteration of your loop

But I don't know what you expect to see for the cells in column I